# Can MS Visual Studio compile projects using 2 or 4 cores on CPU?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it any compilator option of flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can if you setup an external tool pointing to MsBuild to build the solution with the multiple process flag /m.

Scott Hanselman wrote a [nice post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx) on how to accomplish this, so I won't repeat what he has already done.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN answers your question:

[Using Multiple Processors to Build Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383805.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes across this, VS2012 introduced parallel builds as a [standard feature](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/01/more-power.aspx). Quote from the article:

> Visual Studio 2010 included an option for "maximum number of parallel
>   project builds." Although there was no indication of any restriction,
>   this IDE option only worked for C++ projects. Fortunately, this
>   restriction no longer applies to Visual Studio 11. Rather, there's now
>   full support for parallel builds in other languages as well. To view
>   this, run a copy of Process Explorer at the same time a solution with
>   numerous projects is building. You'll see that multiple MSBuild
>   instances are created -- as many as specified in the "maximum number
>   of parallel project builds."